# Type error related to fractions

Tags: haskell, types

Im trying to figure out whats wrong. Seems like something wrong with types, but the same expression alone works fine.

Here is the code:

```
a = [9, 4, 12, 0, -6, 16] :: [Int]

qsort:: [Int] -> [Int] 
qsort [] = []
qsort [x] = [x]
qsort xs = (qsort l)++(qsort r)
    where   m = (realToFrac(sum xs)) / (realToFrac(length xs))
            l = filter (<=m) xs
            r = filter (>m) xs

main::IO()
main = do
        print (show (qsort a))
```

It throws:

```
main.hs:7:36:
    No instance for (Fractional Int)
      arising from a use of `/'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Int)
    In the expression: (realToFrac (sum xs)) / (realToFrac (length xs))
    In an equation for `m':
        m = realToFrac (sum xs) / (realToFrac (length xs))
    In an equation for `qsort':
        qsort xs
          = (qsort l) ++ (qsort r)
          where
              m = realToFrac (sum xs) / (realToFrac (length xs))
              l = filter (<= m) xs
              r = filter (> m) xs
```

But that works well:

```
a = [9, 4, 12, 0, -6, 16] :: [Int]
main::IO()
main = do
    print (show (   (realToFrac(sum a)) / (realToFrac(length a))   ))
```

Comment: Alternative solution: remove the `realToFrac` and use ``sum xs `quot` length xs``; `quot` is division of `Integral` types (that truncates/rounds toward zero; `div` rounds toward -infinity), and since `xs :: [Int]`, `sum xs` and `length xs` have the same type (`Int`), so that works without conversions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `m` definition gives out a number of type `Fractional`.
However you compare `m` to `Int` in the definition of `l` and `r` which confuses the compiler.
The following will do the trick:

```
a = [9, 4, 12, 0, -6, 16] :: [Int]

qsort:: [Int] -> [Int]
qsort [] = []
qsort [x] = [x]
qsort xs = (qsort l)++(qsort r)
    where   m = realToFrac(sum xs) / (realToFrac(length xs))
            l = filter ((<=m) . fromIntegral) xs
            r = filter ((>m) . fromIntegral) xs

main::IO()
main = do
        print (show (qsort a))
```

Answer (score 5):

`realToFrac(sum xs) / (realToFrac(length xs))` does work, but its result is a fractional number. So in your code `m` is a fractional number. But you compare `m` with the items in your list, which are Ints. Since you can only only compare values of the same type and Ints aren't fractional numbers, this causes the type error.

To fix your issue you can either use integer division (`div`) or convert the integers in the list to fractional numbers before comparing them with `m`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But then, why I can do that 4.5 < 5 without errors?

Answer (score 1):

You can use x as your pivot. List pattern matching "qsort (x:xs)" helps a lot here.

```
a = [9, 4, 12, 0, -6, 16] :: [Int]                                                                                    

qsort:: [Int] -> [Int]                                                                                                
qsort [] = []                                                                                                         
qsort (x:xs) = (qsort l) ++ [x] ++ (qsort r)                                                                           
    where   l = filter (<=x) xs                                                                                       
            r = filter (>x) xs                                                                                        

main::IO()                                                                                                            
main = putStrLn $ show $ qsort a   

 -- *Main> main                                                                                                           
 -- [-6,0,4,9,12,16]
```

Alternative syntax as well: http://hpaste.org/81793

Comment: Your edit is incorrect @crimsonlander. Quicksort works by placing each pivot element in the correct place after the filtering process finishes. Therefore [x] must be in the middle of (qsort l) and (qsort r) (its correctly sorted position)

Comment: Sorry, didnt noticed some detail:)